# mail delivery goes wrong with mx lookup

Tags: centos, email, postfix, domain, plesk

in Plesk (11.5) you can deactivate mail service on a specific domain. I did this, because:

At my domain provider I configured the domain DNS settings like this: A-record: IP points to web server with Plesk and Postfix. MX-record: Points still to the domain providers' mail servers (I don't want to use mail at the web server for this one domain).

I get an error message when try send a mail from this webserver with Plesk to an address of this domain which have an external mail server:

```
postfix/smtp[9444]: : to=<xy@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=1.2,
delays=1.1/0.02/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced
(mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself)
```

When I try these command:

```
host -t mx mydomain.com
```

Then these message appears:

```
mydomain.com mail is handled by 10 mail.mydomain.com
```

But I would expect something like:

```
mydomain.com mail is handled by 10 ispmailserver.com
mydomain.com mail is handled by 20 ispmailserver2.com
```

Any further ideas what is wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then set the the DNS names correctly to what you expect?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sebix.... I searched for a way to change the settings within Plesk 11.

So, under the "Domains" section:

[image: Domains section in Plesk]

Choose your domain and change the DNS MX settings to the external mail server. You can add a secondary record if more external mail servers exists and give them a priority.

Regards.